# Moving Shapes as user scrolls right in Excel(VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel workbook with two shapes on Sheet1 like below
[image]

My Requirement is when the user is navigating towards right side of sheet i.e. Towards headers24, header25 and so on ,I want the two shapes on the sheet to move towards the right side with the user.

Can someone Please suggests any ideas for this.

Thanks

Comment: This is easy if you move right/left with the *Arrow* keys or the *Tab* key or the *Enter* key...............not so easy if you use the scroll bars.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: I plan to hide the scroll bar, So user will have to navigate using arrow key only

Comment: I will post some sample code later *(when I get on a computer)* .............we can use an Event Macro to move the Shape when the ActiveCell moves.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent : Yes Please that ll be very helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.. yep, its easy..

Place this code in the worksheet module where the shapes exist.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)

        .Left = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange(2, 2).Left
        .Top = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange(2, 2).Top

    End With

End Sub
```

The coordinate (2, 2) is where you want the shape to be fixed at as you scroll along with the keyboard.

But, it would be annoying to work without the scroll bar on a huge worksheet. so alternatively I think you can use refresh ontime, place this code in a Module

```
Private eTime
Sub ScreenRefresh()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(1)
        .Left = ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).VisibleRange(2, 2).Left
        .Top = ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).VisibleRange(2, 2).Top
    End With
End Sub

Sub StartTimedRefresh()
    Call ScreenRefresh
    eTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime eTime, "StartTimedRefresh"
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    Application.OnTime eTime, "StartTimedRefresh", , False
End Sub
```

And the following code in Sheet1 (where the shapes are in)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Call StartTimedRefresh
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Call StopTimer
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice idea tying the Shape to ActiveWindow *(+1)*

Comment: Very Nice example. It will be helpful if you can explain first part of your solution

Comment: @RohitSaluja, what problem are you facing? are you able to get the first solution running? if you are not sure you have to place the code inside the worksheet module (e.g. Sheet1) where the shapes exist.

Comment: @Rosetta: The code is running fine, but I also want to understand how is it running. So that in Future if something similar arises, I ll be able to code it on my own

Comment: Perhaps `ActiveWindow` is lesser called compared to `ActiveSheet`. Try run `debug.print ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Address`, you'll get the range address of visible cells on your "screen" only. Hence my solution use this address to fix the position of the shape.

Comment: @Rosetta Thanks for explaining it in a detailed manner. I just have one more doubt.The doubt is more of syntactical usage rather than trying to understand the logic. Using `ActiveSheet.Shape(1).Left`  you are trying to fix the left coordinate of the shape and using `ActiveWIndow.VisibleRange(2,2)` you are setting the position of Shape(1) to coordinate (2,2). But I fail to understand the syntax usage as `ActiveWindow.VisibleRange(2,2).Left`

Comment: the syntax is `VisibleRange( [RowIndex], [ColumnIndex])`. So lets say VisibleRange.Address now is `A1:X30`, then VisibleRange(1,1) will be A1, VisibleRange(1,2) will be B1, VisibleRange(2,1) will be A2, VisibleRange(2,2) will be B2, and so on..

Answer (score 3):

First create the shape:

```
Sub Creator()
    Dim shp As Shape

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(1, 100, 10, 60, 60)
    shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "I will follow"
    shp.Name = "MyButton"
End Sub
```

Then in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sh As Shape, r As Range
    Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes("MyButton")
    Set r = ActiveCell
    sh.Top = r.Offset(-1, -2).Top
    sh.Left = r.Offset(-1, -2).Left
End Sub
```

If you move the active cell back and forth, the box will move with it.

***Note:***

This is only demo code.  You still need to:

- add protection to prevent trying to move the Shape "off-screen"
- setting the proper offsets from ActiveCell based on the size of the Shape

Comment: please elaborate `sh.Top = r.Offset(-1, -2).Top`                                                What this line of code is doing ?

Comment: @RohitSaluja  It move the shape's top to a cell two cells to left and one cell below the activecell.....so if the activecell is **F12**, the reference cell is **D11**

Comment: Well, I get it when you do `sh.Top` to set the Top Position of shape. I am also fine with `r.offset(-1,-2)` which says offset by one cell to the left and 2 columns to the left but why the syntax `r.offset(-1,-2).Top` ?

Comment: @rohit saluja, try going to vbe and press F1 when weing on `.top`. For very simple and obvious questions, its better to do a bit of work oneself, no ?